# Is there a tool online that lets me convert acceleration-time graphs into velocity-time and position-time graphs?

Tags: kinematics, resource-recommendations, software, calculus

Basically I need to visualize a few physics exercises and I need a tool that let me to convert the acceleration graphs into the other types So that, I can get an idea of the relation of acceleration time position and velocity.
So are there such tools online or some which I can download?
Basically I'd like to input an acceleration and a it should draw the other graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Given the initial conditions, you can integrate the function and then plot the integral (substituting with appropriate constant and coefficients) on almost all online graphing applications. 
If you don't have a definite function of acceleration and time curve, you should find an approximate type of function that suits the given curve since there is simply no way any application so available can infer from images. You will anyways have to manually input the derived function.

Comment: Numerical integration is ideal for this. No need for "approximate type of function".

Comment: What if you just have a random curve? You need to approximate the nature of the curve first. Also, no clarification is given in the question about the curve and thus I have included both methods in my answer.

Comment: yes, The initial conditions are a must.

Comment: @PranshuMalik numerical methods make no assumptions about the shape of the curve, other than that the function is continuous. More advanced integration methods can account for high orders of changing curvature - in essence the assumption is that over a sufficiently small interval an nth-order Taylor expansion is sufficiently accurate.

Comment: @Floris yes I agree. I have nowhere stated that you need to approximate in the numerical method, but only in the shape (that too only when you aren't provided with the function of acceleration time graph). I don't see how you can just do all that without having the function at your disposal. What I simply mean is that if a curve looks parabolic or just non linearly increasing much like a parabola, take it to be a parabola; obviously exponential regression and stuff can also fit, but isn't relevant

Comment: Taylor series is to break a function into manageable parts. You don't have the function, but the graph. You can only do what I stated. Peace.

Comment: My point is that numerical integration assumes the local curve can be approximated with a polynomial - without needing to know what that polynomial is. The coefficients are computed from multiple points on the curve and this allows for accurate integrations.